# How to show the price with decimal cases in the input but dont have an integer valdidation error on store()?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have the jQuery below and it works, when a value in the price input is inserted, for example "3" it adds "3,00" but then there is a validation error in the controller saying that the price is an integer. Do you know how to correct the issue? That is, maitain the price as an integer but dont have the validation errror.

PostController:

```
$prod = Product::create([
     'price' => $request->price,
]);
```

input:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="price">Price></label>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="any" required class="form-control" value="{{ old('price', '0.00€') }}"  name="price" id="price"/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 document.getElementById("price").onblur =function (){
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,|\€/g, ""))
        .toFixed(2)
        .toString()
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to send a users raw input data to the backend while at the same time displaying their data as formatted on the frontend (in the same input box), you could use a hidden form field which you set once the user has inputed a value.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="price">Price></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="price" />
    <input type="number" min="1" step="any" required class="form-control" value="{{ old('price', '0.00€') }}"  name="show-price" id="price"/>
</div>
```

Then when your user leaves the input field, you can format the input while setting the hidden input to it's raw value pre-formatting:

```
 document.getElementById("show-price").onblur =function (){
    var $price = document.getElementById("price");
    $price.value = this.value;
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,|\€/g, ""))
        .toFixed(2)
        .toString()
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what the input is coming to you as on #show-price, so you might need to format it a little to trim it to a bare integer, but the idea is that before you perform the visual formatting you set your hidden form fields value to that raw data.